# Optimalize MySQL query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have one query, that is comparatively slow. I tried to rewrite it many times, but I cant find better solution. So I want to ask you, if it is written in wrong way from the beginning or it is ok.

```
    SELECT sql_calc_found_rows 
    present_id, present_id, present_url, present_name, present_text_short, foto_name, price_id, price_price, price_amount, price_dis 
    FROM a_present 
    LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT price_id, price_present_id, price_supplier_id, price_dis, price_amount, 
        (CASE WHEN price_dis <> 0 THEN price_dis ELSE price_amount END) as price_price 
       FROM a_price 
       WHERE 
       price_visibility = 1 AND price_deleted <> 1 
       GROUP BY price_id ) pri 
    ON pri.price_present_id = present_id 
    LEFT JOIN _present_fotos ON foto_id = present_title_foto 
    LEFT JOIN _cate_pres ON cp_present = present_id 
    WHERE present_visibility = 1 AND present_deleted <> 1 AND price_price > 0 AND present_out <> 1 AND cp_category IN (30,31,232,32) 
    GROUP BY present_id 
    ORDER BY price_price 
    LIMIT 8
```

Description: price_dis is price after discount, price_amount is price before discount.. Each product (present) has more prices than one.. Is there faster solution to select final price?

If you will find table structure bad, I will be in trouble:)

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
[explain select](http://postimg.org/image/q1spybh4p/)

Comment: you need to show your table structures, query execution plan for us to help you.

Comment: Adding to previous comment - please post what `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` prints - it provides many useful information

Comment: In the subquery on a_price you are grouping by price_id, but selecting a number of other items that are neither grouped nor aggregated - will these fields always have the same values within a group? (If not, the values returned will essentially be random.)

Comment: Mark: after "GROUP BY price_id" I have there sort by price_price.. But i accidentaly deleted it during editing source code.. With this the results is always the same

Comment: Kleskowy: I added link to screen of explain select query.. Thanks

Comment: (Assuming that ORDER BY is in the subquery) While that should work in current versions of MySQL, that behaviour is undocumented - it may work differently in future versions of MySQL (and *will* work differently in MariaDB, the open-source fork of MySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I see a couple of things that could be improved.

**First of all,** you are JOINing with a table derived from a subquery - with subqueries MySQL does not use indexes (hence the slowdown). Instead of joining with a subquery, try JOINing with a table `a_price` itself, and put that `CASE` statement in the original (parent) `SELECT`. It should allow MySQL to use indexes when JOINing, and it is really important, when your subquery returns many rows.

It should look somewhat like this (including `MIN()` and `GROUP BY`, as you need minimum price):

```
SELECT (...), price_amount, price_dis, MIN((CASE WHEN pri.price_dis <> 0 THEN pri.price_dis ELSE pri.price_amount END)) as price_price 
    FROM a_present 
    LEFT JOIN a_price pri 
    ON pri.price_present_id = present_id AND price_visibility = 1 AND price_deleted <> 1 
(...)
GROUP BY present_id
```

**Second of all** - as `EXPLAIN SELECT` suggests - MySQL does not use index on table `_cate_pres`. You should make it use index to JOIN and to select categories you need (since you put some of them in the `IN (..)` statement).

Try adding an index on `_cate_pres.cp_category`, and/or maybe a composite index on this table (using two columns - cp_category and cp_present).

**Generally,** the result you want to achieve (not always it's possible, but in your case I'm pretty sure it is), is to make the following disappear from `EXPLAIN SELECT`:

- [key] NULL - this means no key is used in this particular set
- [Extra] Using temporary - this means a temporary table is created to retrieve results, and it is usually bad for performance
- [Extra] Using filesort - this means no index is used for sorting, so sorting process is slow.

Read more about [indexes in the Mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html), and please give much attention to [EXPLAIN output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: Thanks very much.. But how can I select lowest price for each product (present) with your solution? In my statement I can make it by adding "order by price_price" in that nested select..

Comment: @Michal I updated my answer. Just use `GROUP BY` wisely, you need to group by products, and I assume `present_id` is the product id.

Comment: Yes, present_id is product id:) That solution with MIN looks great.. But I need to select corresponding price_amount to price_price.. I cant just add MIN() to price amount, because If I will have two prices (variants of one product): one with price_dis 500 and price_amount 1000 and the other one with price_dis 800 and price_amount 900... Than I will have price_amount from the second (900) and price_price from the first one (500)... I am right?

Comment: No - it may be random (because the rows are grouped by id). But now I get what you're trying to do. I'd go with creating a view (showing minimum prices for each product), and JOIN with that view - it should be more efficient than a subquery.